# Jxbrowser task manager

Tags: jxbrowser

I created this small application:

```
public class HelloWorld {

   public static void main (String[] args){
         Browser browser = new Browser(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);
         BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);


         final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup");

         frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

         frame.setSize(800, 500);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setContentPane(view);

         browser.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/fglweb/FGL?reportid=139327&tmpext=Local_Dev&type=report");
    }
}
```

When I run it, I can see this 3 jxbrowser-chromium in TaskManager
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior. JxBrowser is based on Chromium engine and inherits its multi-process architecture. There is a main process, and two additional processes for each Browser instance: GPU and renderer. This is why you see three `jxbrowser-chromium.exe` processes in Task Manager.